# Adding a posts count in archive pages

Tags: count

In the category page I need assistance the title is the resort “Lignano Sabbiadoro” , I’d like to display the number of posts (apartments) for this category, maybe in a different color, i.e: Lignano Sabbiadoro (185), with (185) in a custom color. In the future I’ll have a search box with many filters so this count should match the search results.

Here is the category page I'm speaking about: https://sacconicase.com/case-vacanza/italia/friuli-venezia-giulia/lignano-sabbiadoro-appartamenti-vacanze/.

Which is your advice about a code? I think this is the part of the code I should operate in (I got it at the top of the archive/category file):

```
<?php
if ( ! has_post_format( array( 'gallery' ) ) ) :
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
        ?>
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute() ; ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'colormag-featured-image' ); ?>
```

Comment: the title you're referring to doesn't appear in the code you shared can you edit your question and significantly expand the amount of code you shared? What you've shared is unrelated to your question, the main archive title is wrapped in a heading with `page-title` class

Comment: also note that you should ask https://themegrill.com/themes/colormag/ support too, 3rd party theme support is offtopic here so if this question can't be answered using generic WordPress knowledge and requires any knowledge unique to that theme then it would be closed as offtopic

Answer (score 1):

If the theme your're using doesn't do anything fancy, but uses `the_archive_title()` to render the "Lignano Sabbiadoro", then you should be able to modify it with the [`get_the_archive_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_archive_title/) filter.

Something along these lines.

```
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', 'my_get_the_archive_title_filter', 10, 3);
function my_get_the_archive_title_filter(string $title, string $original_title, string $prefix): string {
    if (! is_category()) {
        return $title;
    }

    $current_category = get_queried_object();

    return sprintf(
        '%s <span class="post-count">%d</span>',
        $current_category->name,
        $current_category->count
    );
}
```